# Macbook pro (10.13.2) taking a long time to unlock

Tags: macbook, macos-highsierra

I'm not sure if this is the right forum to ask this question, if not please let me know where would be more appropriate and I'll gladly re-post there.

Anyway to my question. I recently got a 2017 macbook pro from my new job. When I'm in the office (i'm connected to wifi home and office), every time I come back to my desk and unlock my computer, i type in my password and it unlocks instantly.

However if I'm at home or at a friends house, it takes me a good 30 seconds to 1min to unlock!
I've had a look on google and found this terminal command

```
sudo pmset -a standbydelay 86400
```

but its done basically nothing.

Anyone experienced the same problem or have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you bind to Open Directory or Active Directory at work? Does your work network require connecting using a proxy?

Comment: I can't see any info in my network settings that would suggest I am connecting via proxy. The IT guys were a bit vague in their response when I asked them :/
All I got was "looking into a LDAP administrative system that could work on the Macs, not sure if he installed this system on your laptop"